# BibTeX I couldn't open style file ieeetran.bst

Tags: bibtex

I try to create the bibliography for an IEEE paper using www.overleaf.com

I get the following error msg : *BibTeX I couldn't open style file ieeetran.bst : \bibstyle*  output.aux, line 18, using the code fragment below.

```
\section*{References}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}

\bibliography{reference}
```

[image: overleaf files in the project]

the file reference.bib has been used with other projects, the failure should be related to the bibtex setup .

Comment: Try `IEEEtran.bst` instead of `ieeetran.bst`, i.e. use the correct capitalisation. Some systems are case sensitive and need the exact capitalisation of the source file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. LaTeX syntax is case-sensitive. Hence, you need to change `\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}` to `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. (Note the use of uppercase and lowercase lettering in the filenames displayed in the screenshot you posted.) After making the change, be sure to run LaTeX, the BibTeX, and finally LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Note that while Mico is correct in saying that LaTeX (and TeX) is case sensitive (so `\foo` and `\FoO` are different commands), it is slightly more tricky for `.bst` files. Since BibTeX needs to find the file from its file name (without the full path) parts of this rely on your file system. So it becomes relevant if you are using a case sensitive file system. (In TeX live 2018 there was a change that meant that the library used to search files would retry a case-folded search if nothing was found: https://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Casefolding-search). ...

Comment: ... Overleaf is probably using a Linux system with an older TeX live and is therefore case sensitive, hence only `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` works and not `\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}`. I'm on Windows with a new MikTeX installation and my matches are not case sensitive, so `\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}` works for me and finds `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`.

Answer (score 1):

you should check `bst` folder, there are some `bst` files. In my bst folder, it's not `IEEEtran.bst`, it is `ieeetr.bst`. You can change its name according to your `bst` file.

Comment: Well, where does this file `ieeetr.bst` come from? Can you tell the name of the bst folder you mentioned?

Comment: The screenshot in the question shows that the questioner has the right file, i.e., `IEEEtran.bst`, so that is not the problem for this particular question (the problem was using lower case in `\bibliographystyle`). But in general it's good advice to check which `bst` files you have and modify your code according to the actual filename (or vice versa, modify the filename to match your code, unless modifications to the bibliography style file are prohibited by the file license).

Comment: Sorry, i do not see the overleaf. I edit my paper on Windows and get the same error. it worked after i do like what i said. the folder path is 'C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\bibtex\bst\base'

Comment: It's very important to be aware that the `ieeetr` and `IEEEtran` (or `ieeetran`) bibliography styles are not at all the same. If you've been told to employ the `IEEEtran` bib style, using `ieeetr` is *not* an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score -1):

First, you Create the folder:-> "random.bib"
and take bibliography style:-> "\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}"
and call  this file by:-> "\bibliography{random}"

Comment: Why would you use a bibliography `random.bib` but call it using `\bibliography{biblo}`?

Comment: Thanks Werner! Look at the modified  answer. Both name are the same. So instead of taken biblo, here it is random .